# Error in acessing neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

```
gdb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(Neo4J_DBPath);
```

an anyone tell me the Neo4J_DBPath in above line of code. we are working on linux(fedora 19) machine and there is a lock on graph.db file. so we are not able to acess the folder and its telling acess denied. so what will/can be the alternative??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If there's a lock on the db files, it's very likely that there's another Neo4j process that's accessing them. You can only access a database with one process at a time.

If you get an "access denied" message, that means that you check check the folder permissions on `Neo4J_DBPath`.

If you want an in-memory alternative for testing purposes, you can use the ImpermanentGraphDatabase that ships with the following library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can create an ImpermanentGraphDatabase via

```
new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. and i have one more doubt.. actually our main idea is to create a web page(front end) and access the neo4j database(back end) and print again the result again on webpage.. If it is SQL we can connect to the database by using jdbc in jsp/servlet code... but with neo4j is it possible to implement our idea?? do you know like how this can be implemented??